# User session timeout for sonarqube 5.6 version

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis

We have two versions of sonarqubes with versions 6.7x and 5.6x. we want to timeout a user if a user is idle for 20 min. We were successful configuring this in 6.7x version by adding `sonar.web.sessionTimeoutInMinutes=20` in _/Sonar_Home/conf/sonar.properties_. But we want to add for 5.6x version also. when I tried to do same configuration with 5.6x it is not working. Can someone help how we can meet this scenario in 5.6x?

Comment: This could well be a "new" feature. Did you find this setting commented out in the 5.6.x configuration file?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I dont see any conf of user timeout in sonar.properties file. Even though after adding  `sonar.web.sessionTimeoutInMinutes=20` in sonar.properties of 5.6 it didnt worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to configure the web session timeout arrived in SoanrQube 6.x series, see [SONAR-8298](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8298).

No such capability in v5.6.x , which is anyhow end-of-life since late 2017. (read: perfect opportunity to upgrade to v6.7 LTS !)